# Можно ли считать данный код реализацией решета Эратосфена на JS?

Tags: javascript

```js
let arr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 10001; i++) {
  arr[i] = i;
}
for (let z = 2, i = 3, y = 5, x = 7, e = 11, q = 0; q < 10001; z += 2, i += 3, y += 5, x += 7, e += 11, q++) {
  arr[z] = 0;
  arr[i] = 0;
  arr[y] = 0;
  arr[x] = 0;
  arr[e] = 0;
}
for (let i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
  document.write(arr[i] + " " + i + "<br/>")
}
```

слева от i в цикле

```
for(let i = 1; i<1000; i++) {
    document.write(arr[i] + " " + i + "<br/>")
}
```

может выводится либо 0, и тогда это составное число (по моей задумке), либо сама i, тогда это простое число.

Пока что руки не дотянулись проверить везде ли где ноль стоит простое число (с помощью более простого алгоритма который не даст осечек 100%).
В общем простите за незнание теории чисел, то есть за то что я не могу лично математически доказать, что оно выводит только простые числа. Но я каждый день надеюсь, что программирование не только для знающих математику (некоторые области программирования)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Этот код **не является** валидной реализацией решета дедушки Эратосфена.

При работе решета помечаются **все** числа, кратные уже найденным простым. **Всем** найденным. Здесь же по какой-то причине выбраны только пять первых. Нетрудно увидеть, что числа 169, 221 или 289 будут помечены как простые. Дальше можно не продолжать

Answer (score -1):

Нашел код ниже - [здесь](https://qna.habr.com/q/294161), суммы разные, твой код можно считать *Частной* реализацией решета Эратосфена :)

```js
let arr = [];

for (let i = 2; i < 10001; i++) {
  arr[i] = true;
}

let p = 2;
while (p * p < 10001) {
  for (i = 2 * p; i < 10001; i += p) arr[i] = false;
  for (i = p + 1; i < 10001; i++) {
    if (arr[i]) break;
  }
  p = i;
}

let sum = 0;
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i]) sum += i;
}
console.log(sum);
```

"Исправил" твой код, максимум 121, ибо у тебя работать будет только до 11*11

```js
let max = 121;
let arr = [];

for (let i = 0; i < max - 1; i++) {
  arr[i] = i + 2;
}

// let z = 2, i = 3, y = 5, x = 7, e = 11, q = 0;
let z = arr.indexOf(2),
  i = arr.indexOf(3),
  y = arr.indexOf(5),
  x = arr.indexOf(7),
  e = arr.indexOf(11),
  q = 0;

while (q < max) {
  z += 2;
  i += 3;
  y += 5;
  x += 7;
  e += 11;
  arr[z] = 0;
  arr[i] = 0;
  arr[y] = 0;
  arr[x] = 0;
  arr[e] = 0;
  q++;
}
console.log(Object.values(arr));

summ = 0;
for (let e in arr) {
  summ += arr[e];
}
console.log(summ);
```

Comment: 1) не думаю, что здесь уместно понятие "частная реализация", все таки что можно считать за общую? Есть какой либо эталон? По-моему, если эталона нет, а есть лишь знание того каким должен быть результат, то любая реализация, раз уж это одна из реализаций, - частная. 

2) есть ли способ оптимизировать мой код по памяти?

3) мой код неправильно проходит проверку на 11, как вам кажется - почему?

Comment: @Степан 1. юмар + частная означает - "своя"(и не "эталон", а любая реализация которая вернет идентичный ответ, по идентичному запросу, через это сито)

3. нам кажется(так оно и есть), что у кода проблема с цыферами: 2 3 5 7 11 (101 из 129 для 30)

Comment: 1 понял. 3 не понял, что значит "(101 из 129 для 30)".
 Код уже исправил. 11 убрал.

Comment: @Степан [для 30](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Решето_Эратосфена#Пример_для_n_=_30), у тебя не хватает суммы= 2+3+5+7+11, твои коррективы 101 на 102 поменяли, кёк

Comment: @Степан чекни мой ответ еще разб + спасибо за потраченное время

Comment: мне бы модифицировать код для любых диапазонов, а не от 2 до 121... Ладно, спасибо и на том

Comment: @Степан в чем проблема взять тот код, что я написал выше?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106584/discussion-between--and-vadim).